# Building a 32bit xdebug.so for AMPPS 3.2 under MacOSX 10.10 Yosemite

Tags: macos, xdebug

I downloaded the xdebug-2.3.3 source and ran the commands:

1. phpize
2. ./configure --enable-xdebug --with-php-config=/Applications/AMPPS/php-5.6/bin/php-config "CFLAGS=-m32" "CPPFLAGS=-m32" "LDFLAGS=-m32"
3. make
4. lipo -info modules/xdebug.so

It says "Not-fat file: modules/xdebug.so is architecture: x86_64"

I need to compile to 32bit on MacOSX Yosemite as AMPPS can't load a 64bit xdebug.so. Any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

After extracting the source, make sure you `cd` to the root of the extracted files (that is, make sure the current directory contains `Makefile`).

For Step 1:

```
$ /Applications/AMPPS/php-5.6/bin/phpize
```

For Step 2:

```
$ CPPFLAGS="-m32 -I /Applications/AMPPS/extra/include" CFLAGS="-m32" LDFLAGS="-L /Applications/AMPPS/extra/lib" ./configure --enable-xdebug --with-php-config=/Applications/AMPPS/php-5.6/bin/php-config
```

After that, do

```
$ make
$ cp modules/xdebug.so /Applications/AMPPS/php-5.6/lib/extensions/ext
```

Then modify `/Applications/AMPPS/php-5.6/etc/php.ini` by adding the following line:

```
zend_extension = /Applications/AMPPS/php-5.6/lib/extensions/ext/xdebug.so
```

Verify that the installation worked.

```
$ /Applications/AMPPS/php/bin/php --version
PHP 5.6.17 (cli) (built: Jan 10 2016 00:44:01) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v5.0.17, Copyright (c) 2002-2015, by ionCube Ltd.
    with Xdebug v2.4.0RC4, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Retinas
```

You should see the "with Xdebug" in the final line as you do in my example output.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how things didn't work, rather than just slapping a downvote on this?

Comment: Sure. It's been saying that the architecture is incorrect. Well, yesterday I've solved the problem by downloading an older version of xdebug and recompiling normally.